# Interface Builder: Tool Kit (BWtoolkit) Installation

Tags: xcode, plugins, interface-builder

I tried installing [BWtoolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) in my interface builder following the instructions on the BWtoolkit site.

I downloaded the toolkit and installed it by clicking on BWToolkit.ibplugin.

I can see the BWtoolkit when i go to Interface Builder>Preferences>Plug-ins but none of the objects are appearing in the library window.

The only folders that i have are 'Cocoa Touch' and 'Custom Objects'

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BWToolkit is only for Mac OS X projects, it does not have any iPhone components. If you are seeing just Cocoa Touch and Custom Objects under the library pull down then you must be in an iPhone nib file. If you don't have any nib files open IB will default the library display to the last kind of document that was open. Try opening (or creating) and Mac OS X nib and you will see BWToolkit appear (with numerous others sections).

Comment: this may be the case, however in my Mac OS X project I have the same problem, for existing nibs and new ones. The BWToolkit classes are there, in the Objects list I see an empty BWToolkit icon, but no objects. In the Attributes tab the customised properties for the BWTookit object, for example the corner radius in BWGradientBox, are also absent.
I opened the plugin in IB as instructed in the installation doc.